# Full height hero background image resizes on mobile scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, bulma

I am having an issue where the background image I have set for my full height hero is changing sizes when the user scrolls on a mobile device due to the URL bar. This causes the image to snap to the new size when the user scrolls causing a jarring effect. This seems to be a common issue when using `100vh`, so I have tried numerous workarounds, including using js to get the window size on page load and setting the height of the hero manually.  I have an example using Bulma below, which uses `100vh` for its `is-fullheight` hero.

Code: https://codepen.io/Stetzon/pen/JjdQmzN

Demo: https://cdpn.io/Stetzon/debug/JjdQmzN/RBMOJXzxwDbk (must be on mobile to see effect)

Comment: You want the image to always show when the user scroll? I kind of find it hard to see the problem as I currently can't view it on mobile.

Comment: @MosiaThabo No the image should scroll as well, but retain it's original height. It is difficult to troubleshoot because of it only happening on mobile devices, which is the frustrating part

Answer (score 0):

Here's the js that I needed to do for my project.

It gives you the viewport height of the screen when url bar is visible.

`var height = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);`